# How to change pdf page color into red in salesforce cpq quote template

Tags: cpq, quote-template

I need to change pdf page color into red in salesforce cpq quote template.is it possible?

[image]

Comment: do you want just a red color section or a section with fields on top of it?

Comment: @rahulgawale i need red color pdf page not a section

Comment: like red color in the background?

Comment: yes @rahulgawale

Comment: yes i need red color background in cpq quote template

Answer (score 0):

You can create if you have an HTML template content.

In the content section -> click Source -> add below html code to set background color.

```
<div style="background: red;">
     add your content here.
</div>
```

[image]

You can apply HTML tags and style in any template content. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_template_content_html.htm&type=5) are the supported HTML tags.

Comment: we have already used div tag. it changed color only that particular div tag.
suppose we will used two or three section.
But i need to change whole pdf page background color in red..

Comment: Put everything in that div page

Comment: suppose i use line item template content what should happen?

Comment: that you cannot customize.

Comment: any other possibilities?

Comment: No idea may be custom vf template is the last option.